# Negation of a statement for proof by contradiction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

**Question:**Let  be a rational number and  an irrational number. Prove the following:
 ≠  →  is irrational.

Proof by Contradiction:

**Edit**
[image]

I am not sure if my proof is correct. I am having trouble with the proper negation of the statement, do I only need to negate the ($\rightarrow$ ab is irrational) part in the question for the proof?

If yes, then is line 1 in the proof correct, or would it suffice to say **'Suppose $ab$ $ \in$  $\mathbb{Q}$' in line 1, omitting the conditions for a and b,** since they are the stated in the question?

Also, in line 4, do I need to write that **$a$ $\in \mathbb{Q}\  \land a \ne 0$ in order to divide by $a$** or **can I just write divide $ab$ by $a$ to get $b = \frac{md}{nc}$**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. The theorem can be restated as follows: if $a$ is a non-zero rational, and $b$ is irrational, then $ab$ is irrational, which is essentially your first line. Note that it’s not necessary to argue by contradiction: the theorem is logically equivalent to the assertion that if $a$ is a non-zero rational, and $ab$ is rational, then $b$ is rational, which is what you’ve proved directly.

What you need to write depends on the requirements under which you’re working. As an instructor I’d be happy to see something like this:

> Suppose that $a$ is a non-zero rational and that $ab\in\Bbb Q$. Then $a^{-1}$ exists and is rational, so $b=a^{-1}(ab)$ is rational. Taking the contrapositive, we see that if $b$ is irrational, $ab$ must also be irrational.

A proof by contradiction would also be fine, but I’d rather see it in something like this form:

> Let $a$ be a non-zero rational and $b$ an irrational, and suppose that $ab\in\Bbb Q$. Then $a^{-1}$ exists and is rational, so $b=a^{-1}(ab)$ is rational. This contradiction shows that $ab$ cannot rational and must therefore be irrational.

I would prefer **not** to see an argument in the format that you used, with numbered statements and reasons — what I think of as high school geometry style — because it is nothing like normal mathematical writing. (I realize that you may not have a choice in the matter.)

Comment: Is there a theorem used to show that a inverse exists, or does 'a -1 exists' follow naturally from the fact that a is a non-zero rational in this case, so both the denominator and numerator is non-zero, so flipping them will still result in a valid rational a -1? Or is it because for a-1 the denominator is nonzero, so it exists?

Comment: the instructor requires us to number and justify each step, so can I write this instead in line 4: a-1 exists since a-1 = d/c and d, c are both integers with c  not equal to zero. By definition of rational numbers, a-1 is rational. Multiplying by a-1 with ab gives b = md/nc, a rational, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user594831: For your first question, it depends on what you’ve already proved. If you’ve proved that every non-zero rational has a multiplicative inverse, then you immediately have the existence of $a^{-1}$. If not, then you can simply incorporate the proof of that by flipping a fraction with non-zero numberator and observing that the result is a rational number whose product with the original rational is $1$. Yes, at line $4$ I would simply multiply by $\frac{d}c$, justifying its existence by the fact that $c\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I have edited my proof to justify the existence of the inverse of a in line 4, would this proof be correct?

Comment: @user594831: You’re welcome. Yes, that works.